# PHP preg_replace commas select option

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace, explode

How can I replace commas with brakes in select option to change from this:
[image]

To this:

[image]

It seems that my current code doesent work anymore:

```
// $row[1] = "enum('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10')";
$options = explode("', '", preg_replace("/(enum|set)\('(.+?)'\)/", "\\2", $row[1]));
```

Full code from first image:

```
        $row = $db->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM namemap LIKE 'multiplier'");
    $row = $row->fetch_row();

    $options = explode("', '", preg_replace("/(enum|set)\('(.+?)'\)/", "\\2", $row[1]));

    print("<tr><td align='left' class='header'>Multiplier:</td>");
    print("<td align='left' class='lista' colspan='2'><select name='multiplier'>");

    foreach($options as $multiplier) {
        $option = "<option ";

        if ($multiplier == $results['multiplier'])
            $option .= "selected=selected ";

        $option .= "value=".$multiplier.">" . unesc($multiplier) . "</option>";

        print($option);
    }
    print("</select></td></tr>");
```

Comment: can you show what your data source looks like to create the not good image?

Comment: Is from a project of mine, i'm trying to achieve like the second one.

Edit: I added the full code from first image.

Comment: Thanks but still not seeing the data. I see php code but have no idea what the data looks like. Can you do a `echo json_encode($row)` or `print_r($row)`?

Comment: This is the data `Array ( [0] => multiplier [1] => enum('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10') [2] => YES [3] => [4] => 1 [5] => )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I separated the enum string. Not the most elegant thing, but it works:

```
$options = explode(",",str_replace("'","", str_replace('enum(', '', str_replace(')','', $row[1]))));
```

Also I got rid of the `print()` statements. You can output the html directly - separating the html presentation from the php logic helps make the code a little more legible and flexible.

```
<?php

$row = array("multiplier","enum('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10')","YES","","1","");
$options = explode(",",str_replace("'","", str_replace('enum(', '', str_replace(')','', $row[1]))));
?>

<tr><td align='left' class='header'>Multiplier:</td>
<td align='left' class='lista' colspan='2'><select name='multiplier'>
<?php foreach($options as $multiplier) {
    $s='';
    if ($multiplier == $results['multiplier']) $s="selected";
?>
<option value='<?php echo $multiplier?>' <?php echo $s?>><?php echo $multiplier?></option>
<? } ?>
</select></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you found the correct place where it is not working any longer:

> `$options = explode("', '", preg_replace("/(enum|set)\('(.+?)'\)/", "\\2", $row[1]));`

The reason is that the split-string "`', '`" contains a space after the comma while the string returned from `preg_replace` does not have spaces after the comma.

So using *explode* with a fixed string does not suffice any longer as entering these values in the database may be with or without space(s) after a comma (and perhaps even before?).

Once seen, the fix could be straight forward. One solution is to use a regular expression pattern as well when "exploding", there is a sister function for that with `preg_replace` and it is called [`preg_split`](https://php.net/preg_split):

```php
$options = preg_split("/',\s*'/", ...);
                          ^^^
               \s : space character
               *  : zero or more, as many as possible (greedy)
```

So exchanging `explode` with `preg_split` can upgrade the code to handle cases with zero or more space characters after the comma.

Likewise you could introduce potential space characters also before the comma by allowing them the same, just before the comma.